# Как определить с помощью метода ReadLine() есть ли в массиве такое значение?

Tags: c#

Есть массив, в который я занёс страны:

```
string[] countries = { "Ukraine", "Russia", "Indonesia", "China" };
```

и не большой скриптик:

```
string country = Console.ReadLine();
if (country == countries[0]) //Здесь я пробовал делать сравнение по индексам, но это не интересно, и нужно что-то либо проще, либо сложнее, например как-то через циклы..
{
    Console.WriteLine("YES");
}
```

Сама задача в том, чтобы пользователь который ввёл страну в консоли, она сравнивалась со значениями в массиве, не важно сколько значений, главное, чтобы одно из них совпадало, либо ложь.

Comment: `foreach(var c in countries){ if (c == country ) Console.WriteLine("YES");}`

Comment: `if (countries.Contains(country)) { }` `if (Array.IndexOf(countries, country) >= 0) { }`

Comment: @aepot, почему не `Array.IndexOf(countries, country) != -1?`

Comment: @Yotic без разницы.